# Doubtful about what type of JOIN on MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm currently developing a basic web application (using `MySQL` and `PHP`). Its goal is to let me and my colleagues (and also those working in different departments) find, change and arrange work shifts. I have two tables:

- Users
- Shifts

Using the `userId` column in both tables in order to link them.

When a user looks for a different shift, the query is something like this:

```
SELECT 
    s.date, 
    u.lastname, 
    s.shift_to_give, 
    s.seeked_shift,  
    s.notes, 
    s.insert_date
FROM 
   users AS u INNER JOIN shifts AS s 
ON 
   u.userId = s.userId
WHERE
   s.shift_to_give = '$shift_to_give' 
     AND
   (*) u.office = (
        SELECT 
           office 
        FROM 
           users 
        WHERE 
           employee_number = '$employee_number' ) 
     AND
  (**) s.status != '1' 
     AND
    s.date='$date' 
     AND 
 (***) s.userId != (
        SELECT 
           userId 
        FROM 
           users 
        WHERE 
           employee_number = '$employee_number' );
```

The parameters I want to take care of are:.

1. Each user can obviously see the shifts requests pertaining to his own office (The employee number is already stored with the session from the login.
2. The "status" column is a flag for making out requests that have already been processed
3. In search mode each user doesn't see his own requests.

With this statement I have results even when I shouldn't be supposed to.
(`if($r)` is always true)

How could I do to make it work properly?

---

After this query, the code continues like so:

$result = mysqli_query($dbc,$query);

```
    if ($result)    // If there are results
    {       
    echo "There are x records found..";
    mysqli_free_result($result);
    mysqli_close($dbc);
    }   

    else
    {
    echo "No results :-(";
    }
```

If I have any results with my query they are correctly displayed (by checking manually into the db) BUT it never goes to the "else" statement, even when I look for something that doesn't exist...instead, I see a blank page.
Any suggestions?
Meanwhile, thanks for replying so far :-)

Comment: There was a "Hello everybody" at the beginning..I wrongly deleted it

Comment: `if ($r)`? What is that? I don't see anything related in the query.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by getting results when you shouldn't? What kind of data results in correct results versus incorrect?

Comment: It looks like you're concatenating/inserting strings into your statement directly from PHP.  Don't do that - it leaves you very vulnerable to SQL Injection, and can be found by automated tools.  Use parameterized statements instead.  Other than that, the query looks like it should be mostly correct; for better help, please provide sample starting data, and anticipated results for a set of input.

Comment: After the query I posted, the code continues like so: